# Fixing tables in orgtbl-mode

Tags: org-table

So I had a table that looked like this

```
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|          Version          |            Minimum OS Requirements             |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2019 Express    |Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016               |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2017 Express    |Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2           |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2016 Express    |Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012                |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2014 Express    |Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1     |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2012 Express    |Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1     |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2008 R2 Express |Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2    |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2008 Express    |Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2    |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2005 Express    |Windows XP SP3 or Windows Server 2003 SP2       |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Then I noticed that "Express" needs to be after "Server" in the first column.

So,

```
replace-string Express->""
```

Here's the result :

```
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|          Version          |            Minimum OS Requirements             |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2019     |Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016               |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2017     |Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2           |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2016     |Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012                |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2014     |Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1     |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2012     |Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1     |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2008 R2  |Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2    |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2008     |Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2    |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|SQL Server 2005     |Windows XP SP3 or Windows Server 2003 SP2       |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I fix the table?

Comment: This is *NOT* an Org mode table, syntactically speaking, so any attempt to use Org mode means to format it is bound to fail.  In [Org mode tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html), every row (including separator or so-called "hline" rows) starts and ends with `|`, the pipe character. The fact that your table uses `+' at the beginning and end of the separator rows makes this a different kind of table (a so-called [table.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) table).

Answer (score 0):

'C-c C-c' realigns the table.

See Section 17.7 of the org-mode manual, [The Very Busy ‘C-c C-c’ Key](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Very-Busy-C_002dc-C_002dc-Key.html).

Comment: here's how it looks after C-c C-c : https://i.imgur.com/gv5ptxt.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the initial table.

It should look like this instead :

```
| Version            | Minimum Os Requirements                      |
|--------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2019    | Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016            |
| SQL Server 2017    | Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2        |
| SQL Server 2016    | Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012             |
| SQL Server 2014    | Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1  |
| SQL Server 2012    | Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1  |
| SQL Server 2008 R2 | Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2 |
| SQL Server 2008    | Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2 |
| SQL Server 2005    | Windows XP SP3 or Windows Server 2003 SP2    |
```

There *can* be separators between rows; e.g. this is a perfectly legal Org mode table:

```org
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| Version             | Minimum Os Requirements                      |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2019     | Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016            |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2017     | Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2        |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2016     | Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012             |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2014     | Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1  |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2012     | Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1  |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2008 R2  | Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2 |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2008     | Windows Vista SP2 or Windows Server 2008 SP2 |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
| SQL Server 2005     | Windows XP SP3 or Windows Server 2003 SP2    |
|---------------------+----------------------------------------------|
```

but it has to be syntactically correct: every row (including `hline`s or separator rows) has to start and end with `|`, a "pipe" symbol. See the [Tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html) chapter in the Org mode manual.

OTOH, the separators add clutter, so they are generally used sparingly: to separate headers from the body of the table, and sometimes to separate the body of the table from a summary row at the end. See examples in the [various table tutorials on Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/#Spreadsheet).